# Ruby on rails - STRIPE API KEY

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error with strip :

[image]

I have visited https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js
but I am not sure where to put this script tags 
does it go in the

```
 {new.html.erb | create.html.erb | charges.html.erb}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx');
</script>
```

Comment: share your code like upload on github

Comment: put your code in application.html.erb and tell me does it work  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your test key from this post.

You need to set the publishable key inside a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: {new.html.erb | create.html.erb | charges.html.erb} I know that but iniside what file does this script tag go in

Comment: @Que I would include the script and set the publishable key in a script tag in the application layout.

Comment: ohkay thanks ill try that , and dont worrie guys this isnt my actual public key xD

Answer (score 0):

It could be several issues:

1. Check, please, your API key in Stripe account settings (probably it
   was changed).
2. Be sure that command "Stripe.setPublishableKey('...')"
   is running (cache? forgot reloading page? etc...).

Comment: Sorry but this was not helpful